# Chrome "Drop workspace folder here"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

While developing some JavaScript using Chrome 38.0.2125.122 m Developer Tools, I clicked on an error in the JavaScript console and was met with the following message:

> Drop workspace folder here

[image: Drop workspace folder here]

Why isn't Chrome taking me to the offending line on the offending file, as usual? What is a workspace folder? What am I expected to do?

Comment: Wow! What the heck. I have never seen anything like that. Is it something to do, perhaps, with syncing localhost files (or like adding source maps for post-processed HTML/CSS or something)? I've seen the release notes for those new features but have never dug into them.

Comment: Probably not expected behavior.

Comment: Had this too. Restarting chrome and reopening the dev tools fixed it.

Answer (score 41):

Seems like it is another way to add a workspace to the DevTools (another way of doing this: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces#).
It happened for me when I dragged a file to an open browser page and the file was accidentally dragged over the open DevTools. If you want this to go away you can drag and drop a dummy file. This way there is no need to restart Chrome.

Comment: just closing and re-opening the dev tools seems to solve as well in chrome 75+ (either manually or using `F12`)

Comment: Yep, just close the dev tools and reopen them and that should fix it. Interestingly, Firefox has the same bug.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't even need to drop a dummy file... just drag a dummy file over and then out of the panel.

Answer (score 10):

This happens in recent versions of Opera browser too.

For me it happens when I drag a file or folder over any part of the dev panel, even while it is behind other programs or folders.

The prompt does not always stick, but when it does, dragging any file off my desktop back over the dev panel usually un-sticks it. It doesn't seem necessary to drop the file in the prompted area, but that works too.

In addition to Alexandra's answer link, there're discussions on the GoogleChrome git pages discussing 'workspaces'.. personally I don't use it, I prefer a full editor.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to restart Chrome. Closing and reopening the tab does the trick.